# Java. How to get non-nullable fields by reflection?

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection, annotations

I try to get list of fields from class (hibernate entity). Like this:

Entity:

```
public class A {

    public static final Integer someValue = 1;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "a_id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_b_id", nullable = true)
    private List<B> b;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "a_c_id")
    private C c;

    .........................
}
```

Method for getting non-static fields:

```
public static List<Field> getNonStaticFields(Class clazz) {
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    List<Field> fieldsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (!Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
            fieldsList.add(field);
        }
    }

    return fieldsList;
}
```

But I need to get only non-nullable non-static fields. This means that I need to get fields with `@NotNull` annotation and `@JoinColumn` annotation with parameter "`nullable = false`".

Check for `@NotNull` is simple:

```
field.isAnnotationPresent(NotNull.class)
```

But I have no idea how can I check field for `@JoinColumn` with parameter.
How can I do it? Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2):

For the annotation `JoinColumn`, you simply needs to get it first with [`getAnnotation(Class<T> annotationClass)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-) then check the value of `nullable()`.

The resulting filter could then be:

```
...
if (!Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
    // Add the field to the list only if it is annotated with NotNull
    // or annotated with JoinColumn and nullable is false
    JoinColumn jc;
    if (field.isAnnotationPresent(NotNull.class) || 
        ((jc = field.getAnnotation(JoinColumn.class)) != null && !jc.nullable())) {
        fieldsList.add(field);
    }
}
..
```

Comment: I will try this solution. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is there a way to access the getters for these fields? If I do field.get(), it throws `java.lang.IllegalAccessException` as the member is private in the entity. Any suggestions?

Comment: @infinite in case of private member, you need to make it accessible first, have a look to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#setAccessible(boolean)